# Absolute/relative address in ajax call in jquerymobile

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

The following code works fine in iPads and iPhone (4,5) in Safari and Chrome.  In contrast, the ajax call won't work (runs straight to the onError function) in Android devices and desktop browsers.

When I exchange the absolute URL for a relative one, the success/failure outcomes are reversed in these two groups.

How do I get around this problem (I'm running jquerymobile 1.3.0 beta)?  Thanks/Bruce

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var formData = $("#loginf").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mydomain.org/m2/scripts/site/bpg_process.asp?id=lg",
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
  });
  return false;
});
});
```

Comment: And what is a message returned to onError function in android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know that cross-domain Ajax calls are not allowed ?
Your problem may be linked to the URL **from which** you're making the request, and not to the browser you're testing in.
Read this for more details : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

The important thing here for you is that the policy excludes different subdomains.
Ex. if you're sending a request from http://www.mydomain.org to http://mydomain.org **it will fail**, and vice versa.

What i do in your case usually is use the complete URL "`/m2/scripts/site/bpg_process.asp?id=lg`" without the protocol and host but with the starting "/" so it can be referenced from anywhere in the URL tree.

What is the "relative URL" that you're using and that "doesn't work"?

Comment: Thanks.  The URL-the protocol was the solution. I appreciate your time. Bruce

Answer (score 0):

Like darma has mentioned. "cross-domain Ajax calls are not allowed".

Use absolute "local" pathing instead.

a slash '/' at the beginning of a link referees to the document root.

if you need to refer to an external domain, use ajax to call a local .asp document that calls the external page for you and returns the data you want in json.

Im not sure what this is in asp but in php, curl works.